# How can I read static files from a bazel target?

Tags: go, bazel

I have a test that I want to run using `go_test`, however it reads in some files in order to run the test - in this case, an Excel file.

When I try to run the test, I attempt to read the relative path to the file `"testdata/good_file.xlsx"`, but I get a file not found error. If I run the test normally using `go test` it works fine. How can I read this file from my test in bazel?

Answer (score 4):

Note that this answer will work for all languages, not just Go. It will also work for binaries like `go_binary` or `go_image`, not just tests.

Bazel attempts to create a hermetically-sealed environment for your binary, which means that anything that is not explicitly specified in the `BUILD.bazel` file is ignored and from the perspective of anything that is running, does not exist.

To include it is fairly straightforward. You first create a `filegroup` target that wraps the data:

```py
filegroup(
    name = "testdata",
    srcs = [
        "testdata/good_file.xlsx",
    ],
    # Alternatively you can use a glob if you want to get all the Excel files, which is usually
    # the case when working with tests:
    # srcs = glob(["testdata/*.xlsx"]),
)
```

Then in your test target, you include the data using the `data` attribute:

```py
go_test(
    name = "my_test",
    # ... some fields ...
    data = [
        ":testdata",
    ],
    # ... more fields ...
)
```